# Usage of QgsVectorFileWriter.ActionOnExistingFile() in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, vector-layer, save, writers

I am currently trying to find a way to overwrite a CSV file saved in my QGIS project as a component in my larger project to save files. The end goal is that the CSV is 1) saved if the project has not been saved before or 2) overwritten and saved again if the project has been saved before.

The reason why I am having so much trouble is that I continuously get win32 errors where it tells me the file is open and being used by another process. I am hoping to find a way around this to overwrite files by using built-in QGIS functions.

I found this function called `ActionOnExistingFile` with an enumerator `CreateOrOverwriteFile` buried in some [older QGIS documentation](https://api.qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#afda86eff21ac1da7dc42cbdde424acb1), but was confused as to how to implement it. Unsure if it is even relevant anymore in newer versions of QGIS. I think it would solve my problem if I could understand how to use it in my code.

This is what I am currently trying to add it to:

```py
error, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_file, "utf-8", layer.crs(), "CSV")
```

Any insight on how to implement this?